# Token is coming null

Tags: hashicorp-vault

private static final String VAULT_ADDR = "http://localhost:8200";
private static final String VAULT_TOKEN = "root";

public static void main(String[] args) throws VaultException, IOException {
final VaultConfig config = new VaultConfig()
.address(VAULT_ADDR)
.token(VAULT_TOKEN).sslConfig(new SslConfig().verify(true).build());

```
    final Vault vault = new Vault(config);

    // Enable the Transit secret engine
    vault.logical().write("sys/mounts/transit", new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("type", "transit");
    }});

    // Create a new encryption key
    vault.logical().write("transit/keys/my-token2", new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("type", "aes256-gcm96");
    }});

    // Encrypt a file using the encryption key
    byte[] plaintext = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/home/sourav/Desktop/newvaultdemo/file/adapter.txt"));
    LogicalResponse ciphertextResponse = vault.logical().write("transit/encrypt/my-tokenKey", new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("plaintext", Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(plaintext));
    }});

    Map<String, String> ciphertextData = ciphertextResponse.getData();
    System.out.println(ciphertextData);
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("ciphertext", ciphertextData.get("ciphertext"));
    System.out.println(data);
    vault.logical().write("secret/data/my-secret", data);
```

Comment: I want to encrypt files in java using hashicorp vault but token is coming null